# Indicating someone else made a guess about past events

Tags: grammar, past-tense, conditional-constructions

Imagine the following scenario: You were in class, and your professor made a guess and said

> Professor: "Climate change may have led the dinosaur to extinction."

After the class, you are about to say this sentence to your colleagues. Would you say

> (A) The professor mentioned that climate change may have led the dinosaur to extinction.

or

> (B) The professor mentioned that climate change might led the dinosaur to extinction.

or

> (C) The professor mentions that climate change may have led the dinosaur to extinction.

In fact, my question is essentially that when you want to express someone **made** a guess about the **past** event, how can we say it correctly?

By the way, I include (C) as part of possible options because it seems like when people talk about something in the past, they sometimes use the present tense rather than the past tense. Still, as a non-native speaker, I'm not really sure which is correct. I'm quite confused about it.

So, I would like to know which is the correct way to say. Or is neither of them correct by any chance? If so, how can I say it for this? I will appreciate any comment!

Comment: _Extinct_ is an adjective, so we have to say that the dinosaurs _became extinct_. There is some ambiguity about whether to use _may_ or _might_, but I would say "The professor mentioned that climate change may be the reason that dinosaurs became extinct."

Comment: What Kate said, or replace "*to extinct**" with "*to **extinction***".

Comment: In order to save us effort in answering, please use the "Edit" button on your question to add what you already know about shifting tenses in indirect speech. Also, please tell us what research you've done on your own to answer this question before asking here, and what about it didn't satisfy you

Comment: I think there's a *potential* nuance of difference in using ***mentioned*** rather than the obvious verb ***said*** in such contexts. Maybe it's just me, but I think ***mentioned*** implies an assertion (regardless of any possible qualifiers such as ***may / might** have*) that's *known and/or believed by many people*, whereas if he simply ***said*** that something might be true, it's possible the professor is in fact the only person who ever made or believed that assertion.

Comment: @gotube Ahh.. I didn't know there's a term until u told me. I just read the grammar tip from Cambridge dictionary and I think I have figured it out and the appropriate response would go to (A) (see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech-indirect-speech). (C) is also correct if the speaker is using the time shift to show vividness (see https://www.thoughtco.com/tense-shift-verbs-1692461). Is that correct?

Comment: I think (B) is not correct in this context. To my best understanding, 'might' suggests a guess for a future event, but the extinction had happened so it should not be 'might' but 'may have' as indicated in (A).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A is correct. B is nearly correct,  you'd say "...might have led...". C is incorrect, in context, because the Professor is not mentioning as you speak, nor is it a general truth that the professor always mentions this.  You are referring to a past event, so need a past tense for "mention".

You might use "mentions" in the present tense when referring to a book written by the professor. The act of writing preserves the act of "mentioning" and makes it presently true.

When reporting speech you describe the meaning of what was said. The meaning of "may" and "might" are similar enough (in context) that either could be used. Often when reporting speech you use the same phrasing as the original speaker, but this isn't a grammar rule. It would be possible to report what was said in lots of ways "The professor said that the extinction of the dinosaurs could have been caused by climate change." That preserves the meaning, but not the phrasing.

Now, you might (rarely) use the "historical present".  This is highly marked.  It sounds odd - deliberately - to make a point.

> Yeah, so, I'm sitting there, and in comes the Professor, and he starts waffling on as usual.  Then suddenly he mentions that that climate change may have led to the extinction of the dinosaurs.  Well, you can imagine what happens next....

It is not common, and learners should use this very cautiously, as it can be misunderstood.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation but when it comes to historical present (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present), does (C) become correct? That is, we can say (C) to show the vividness, can't we?

Comment: The historical present is highly "marked".  In the context given (discussing a lecture with colleagues) the use of the historical present would seem very odd.  However if it was part of a longer narrative it might be possible, I'll edit.

Answer (score -1):

“May” suggests a high degree of probability and "might" is appropriate for past-tense uncertainty and lower probability.  Science shows it could have also been from a meter shower and that caused the major climate change.  So "may" leans towards greater certainty would be accurate as told.

Comment: comments invited.

Comment: I don't accept that *“may” suggests a high degree of probability than "might"* in any meaningful sense. I'm aware that *some* people think this, but imho they represent a tiny minority of all Anglophones. So even if those particular people do in fact implement the principle in their own usage, it means nothing if the audience / readership don't recognise any such distinction anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers   It seems your opinion is the minority   https://www.masterclass.com/articles/may-vs-might-explained#Q11GNyOQ2S29BFAbdV86U

Comment: Like I said, I don't buy that perspective. I think it primarily originates with grammarians and non-native speakers, who are always keen to find *semantic* distinctions between alternatives, even though often the difference is either fictitious or is simply a matter of "style / register". Actual native speakers would rarely have any reason to look up a possible semantic distinction between common alternative phrasings, but it's the kind of thing people involved in TEFL are always preoccupied with.

Comment: I'm a  3rd generation Canadian  from English-Scottish background and this is common to my experiences in the last half century.  Note the credentials of the authors of that link.  FWIW @FumbleFingers  . But I agree with you, not everyone implies this rank of uncertainty.

Comment: I just checked Google Books for several permutations of *[didn't] **...say may I said might, say might he said may,...*** on the assumption that with 40 million books scanned, if there genuinely *was* any such distinction recognised by any significant proportion of the Anglophone population, there should be at least *one* written instance of someone clarifying the degree of uncertainty intended, by calling attention to the choice of vocabulary. I got no hits, just as I expected.

Comment: You might be correct. They may be equal. Yet perhaps the interpretation may be who is involved and the strength of supporting facts and the confidence in knowing or trusting the bias of who said it. It may be accurate to say well-funded news agencies are clearly partisan according to research analysis. But it might also be a biased analysis. ;)